# IONIC - VERIFICAR SE UM IFRAME FOI CARREGADO 100%

Tags: ionic, iframe

Estou incorporando um iframe com um link do google maps dentro da minha aplicação ionica, como faço para verificar se o frame foi carregado 100%? Pois, dependendo da conexão de internet do usuário, pode levar alguns segundos para ser carregado e durante esses segundo, eu gostaria de realizar um ação.

Comment: Como você está chamando o iframe? apenas no HTML?

Comment: Sim, Felipe....

Comment: <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3656.976123884744!2d-46.65830728502199!3d-23.56930098467905!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x94ce59c41d440a33%3A0xfde78c1318fcbc9c!2sAlameda+Campinas%2C+977+-+Jardim+Paulista%2C+S%C3%A3o+Paulo+-+SP%2C+01404-001!5e0!3m2!1spt-BR!2sbr!4v1530191321720" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o event-bind do angular: (load)="funcaoExecutadaAoConcluirOLoad()"

Como no exemplo abaixo:

```
<iframe name="chatFrame" src="http://..." (load)="dismissLoading()"></iframe>
```

A funçao que for indicada no load será executada ao final do carregamento